# Как вызвать фокус в поле ввода и сделать принудительный вызов клавиатуры в React?

Tags: reactjs, input, inputmask

Есть компонент `input`'а. К нему прикручена маска `react-input-mask`. Нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы поле ввода было с фокусом и показана клавиатура(в данном случае цифровая).

```
<InputMask
 ref={this.inputRef}
/>
```

На `componentDidMount` компонента вешаю:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.inputRef.focus();
}
```

И оно работает на десктопе. А в телефоне как-то странно. При переходе на страницу - фокуса нет. Но если ткнуть в поле и перезагрузить страницу, то фокус остается. Но клавиатура в любом случае не показывается. Пробовал отключить пакет с маской - клавы так же нет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно так:

```
<InputMask
  ref={(input) => { this.inputRef = input; }} 
/>
```